# How to get the DataRowView when DataSource is a generic collection List<T>?

Tags: c#, winforms

The DataGridView is bound to a List.

```
 public class Foo
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
    }
```

Form load event:

```
        ds = new List<Foo>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            ds.Add(new Foo { A = i });
        }
        bs = new BindingSource { DataSource = new BindingList<Foo>(ds) };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

The following code got a run-time error on the cast of `(DataRowView)`. The type is `Foo`

```
        var foo = (DataRowView) dataGridView1.Rows[990].DataBoundItem;
        foo["B"] = "....";
        foo.EndEdit();
```

Comment: You aren't using a `DataTable`, so why do you want a `DataRowView`?

Comment: I want to change the value on the UI (from a stream) constantly and I don't want to refresh the data source (which will cause the scroll bar to go to the top). DataTable is heavier to setup.

Answer (score 0):

DataBoundItem is type of Foo... There is no DataRowView available since there is no DataTable because the source is a List...

You may write:

```
var foo = (Foo)dataGridView1.Rows[990].DataBoundItem;
foo.B = "....";
((BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource).ResetBindings(false);
```

*That seems to work like that:*

*To refresh the view of a modified DataBoundItem that is an object of a DataSource that is a BindingList or simply a List, we can reassign the DataSource.*

*But if it's a BindingSource you can use ResetBindings on the BindingSurce.*

*But if you use a DataTable instead of a DataSource on a List then you can use EndEdit on the DataBoundItem that is a DataRowView.*

*Then the question is what does it is best to do here: use a BindingSource on a List or create a DataTable and manage the LoadFromStream and SaveFromStream, since you said that the data come from a IEnumerable<> stream?*

*Therefore you can see CopyToDataTable() to map your List to a DataTable:*

[Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

Comment: The problem is ResetBindings() reset the DataGridView so the scroll bar will go to the top.

Comment: The problem is that you modify a DataBoundItem and not the Cell value itself and you don't have a DataTable to be able to use an EndEdit method on a DataRowView. You may prefer using ADO.NET instead of a List to present interactive data to user, as I know.

Comment: The data will not come from Ado.Net. It will be streamed.

Answer (score 0):

```
           //hope it helps
            DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)tbl_perDataGrid.SelectedItem;
            //if multiple selection
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)t_datagrid.SelectedItems[0];
            string s = row["name"].ToString();
            ----------------------------------------more useful code for working with DataRowView   
            ///getting column
                int i = (int)((DataRowView)t_datagrid.SelectedItems[0])["id"];

            ///with indexes
                //-------------------------------------
                DataGridRow row1 = e.Row;

                int row_index = ((DataGrid)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row1);
                int numberOfColumns = ((DataGrid)sender).Columns.Count;

                //-----------------------------------
```